# How to solve this system of Modular equations?

Tags: equation-solving

I mean

```
{Mod[31*x + y, z] == 29, Mod[29*x + y, z] == 2, Mod[2*x + y, z] == 26}
```

Here is my unsuccessful try

```
FindInstance[{Mod[31*x + y, z] == 29, Mod[29*x + y, z] == 2,Mod[2*x + y, z] == 26}, 
{x, y, z}, Integers]
```

> FindInstance::nsmet: The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist.

The same results are obtained with `Solve` and `Reduce`.

Comment: Perhaps `ChineseRemainder` would help...

Comment: @David G. Stork: Thank you for your edit: now the title is exacter formulated. Can  you kindly elaborate your comment?

Comment: Look up `ChineseRemainder[]`, which solves systems of Modular equations under certain general conditions on the relative primeness of the terms.

Comment: @David G. Stork: Don't see how to realize your idea.

Answer (score 5):

Sort of embarassed I forgot this method for a few days. Anyway, one can get a set of possible moduli that work by computing what is called a strong Groebner basis of the defining polynomials over the integers. This happens to be the type computed by `GroebnerBasis` with the setting `CoefficientDomain->Integers`.

```
polys = {31*x + y - 29, 29*x + y - 2, 2*x + y - 26};
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, {x, y}, CoefficientDomain -> Integers]

(* Out[221]= {-777, -1 - y, 375 + x} *)
```

The important point is that, for the equations to have solutions, 777 must be equivalent to zero. That can only happen if the modulus is a factor of 777, which is to say, one of the divisors. Below are the nontrivial ones (that is, discarding 1).

```
moduli = Rest[Divisors[777]]

(* Out[225]= {3, 7, 21, 37, 111, 259, 777} *)
```

Solutions for a give divisor `d` might obtained using `Solve` with `Modulus->d`. Example:

```
Solve[polys == 0, {x, y}, Modulus -> moduli[[-3]]]

(* Out[236]= {{x -> 69, y -> 110}} *)
```

--- edit ---

Since the equations are linear one can also just use the Hermite normal form of the augmented matrix. This is obtained as the second matrix in the result from `HermiteDecomposition`. It corresponds to the reduced row echelon form, except division is not allowed.

```
polys = {31*x + y - 29, 29*x + y - 2, 2*x + y - 26};
{rhs, mat} = Normal[CoefficientArrays[polys, {x, y, z}]];
newmat = Join[mat, Transpose[{rhs}], 2]

(* Out[299]= {{31, 1, 0, -29}, {29, 1, 0, -2}, {2, 1, 0, -26}} *)

{umat, hnf} = HermiteDecomposition[newmat]

(* Out[300]= {{{-13, 14, -1}, {-1, 1, 1}, {-27, 29, -2}}, {{1, 0, 0, 
   375}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 777}}} *)
```

Reading from the last row of `hnf`, we see that `777==0` is a requirement for a solution to exist. The other rows tell us that `x==-375` and `y==-1`

--- end edit ---

Comment: Very systematic way !

Answer (score 3):

You can rewrite the equations without `Mod` by introducing extra variables.

```
{x, y, z} /. FindInstance[31 x + y == k1 z + 29 && 29 x + y == k2 z + 2 && 2 x + y == k3 z + 26, {x, y, z, k1, k2, k3}, Integers, 3]

(* {{47, 39, 1}, {-39, -19, -1}, {-43, 0, 1}} *)
```

If you don't want trivial solutions with `|z| = 1`, you can just add another inequality.

Comment: +1. This is a big step. But how to find all the solutions of the system under consideration? Solve produces a strange result.

Answer (score 3):

Smallest solution I found is `{x->32,y->36,z->37}`. I found this by taking the equations and rewriting each of them to be `Mod[y,z]=r`:

```
29==Mod[31x+y,z] -> Mod[29-31x,z]==Mod[y,z]
2==Mod[29x+y,z] -> Mod[2-29x,z]==Mod[y,z]
26==Mod[2x+y,z] -> Mod[26-2x,z]==Mod[y,z]
```

Then you can solve for `y` using `ChineseRemainder`:

```
ChineseRemainder[{29-31x,2-29x,26-2x},{z,z,z}]
```

This will yield a solution so long as `x` and `z` are chosen such that a solution exists.

To find such `x` and `z`, brute force was used:

```
dat = Table[{x, z, ChineseRemainder[{29 - 31 x, 2 - 29 x, 26 - 2 x}, {z, z, z}]}, {x, 1, 100}, {z, 30, 2000}];
DeleteCases[Flatten[dat, 1], {_, _, ChineseRemainder[_, _]}] (* to remove all unevaluated cases *)
```

Note that this returns in the order `{x,z,y}`.

```
{Mod[31 x + y, z] == 29,
 Mod[29 x + y, z] == 2,
 Mod[2 x + y, z] == 26} /. {x -> 32, y -> 36, z -> 37}
```

> ```
> {True, True, True}
> ```

---

In an attempt to generalize the solution, we can attempt to simplify the original equations by adding and subtracting them from each other:

```
Mod[29-31x,z]==Mod[y,z]==Mod[2-29x,z] -> Mod[27-2x,z]==0
Mod[26-2x,z]==Mod[y,z] && Mod[27-2x,z]==0 -> Mod[y,z]==Mod[-1,z]

Mod[2-29x,z]==Mod[y,z]==Mod[26-2x,z] -> Mod[24+27x,z]==0
Mod[27-2x,z]==0==Mod[24+27x,z] -> Mod[375+x,z]==0 -> Mod[x,z]==Mod[-375,z]
```

From here we can write these equations in terms of arbitrary integer constants `k1` and `k2`:

```
x == k1 z - 375
y == k2 z - 1
```

Which describes a solution set so long as the base case is satisfied (plug in the case when `k1` and `k2` are both 0 to the original equation). Simplifying that condition, we find that:

```
Mod[-777,z] == 0
```

Is another necessary condition, which is satisfied if `z` equals 37, 111, 259, or 777; or possibly some negative `z` values as well.

Comment: Thank you. The question " How to obtain all the solutions?" remains open.

Comment: @user64494 I have generalized the solution to the best of my abilities by applying the steps in the first half of my answer more completely. I'm somewhat surprised that `Solve` is as unhelpful as it is in this work though.

Comment: There are also solutions mod 3 and 7. Those are the only other primes for which i could find solutions. I do not have a proof that there are no other such but suspect that is in fact the case.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Neat, though I interpreted `Mod[31*x + y, z] == 29` in the original problem to mean that at least that modulus needs to be 29 exactly, requiring $z>29$. 3 and 7 do meet the condition I found there, `Mod[-777,z]==0`. 21 also.

Comment: That's a fair interpretation I think. As best I can tell, the only moduli that work are of the form `3^r*7^s*37^t` with `{s,t}` all in the set `{0,1}`.